# How can I check if a select dropdown in iframe changed?

Tags: jquery, select, iframe

I have a select dropdown in the iframe, but I want to check that out of the iframe if changed. 
I wrote it this way, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // var iframe = $("#spin-frame");
    // var result = iframe.contents().find("#result-select");

    var result;

    $("#spin-frame").bind("load",function(){
        result = $(this).contents().find("#result-select");
    });

    result.live('change', function() {
        // TODO 
    });

});
```

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from the same domain as the webpage?

Comment: @Turnip yes, it's from same Domain

Comment: Also, `.live()` was removed in jQuery 1.9. You should be using `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

As the content of the `iframe` is on the same domain as the parent page then you can attach the event handler directly to the `#result-select` element you retrieve using `contents()`:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#spin-frame").bind("load",function(){
    result = $(this).contents().find("#result-select").on('change', function() {
      let value = $(this).val();
      console.log(value);

      // work with the selected value here..
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that `live()` was deprecated from jQuery a long time ago and should not be used. In addition, check the version of jQuery you're using as it may be out of date. The latest public version, at time of writing, is 3.5.0.

Comment: Thank you Rory, but It works when we click directly on Select, the problem is that the select value is also changed by js in the iframe.

Comment: we don't change values of Select directly

Comment: There's no event raised when a `select` is changed programmatically. Your only choice in that scenario is to manually raise the event by using `trigger('change')` after you set the `val()`, or to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)